# How to switch labels around on GGPLOT bargraph after mean separation?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to switch labels to where they should be on a `ggplot` bar graph (after mean separation). I am using R 3.6.2. I have used the `HSD.test` from the `agricolae` package to do mean separation, but I can't figure out how to switch the letters around on the top of the graph. I am comparing different performance ratings on three different trucks with 4 different engines. Here is the data, and the end result:

```
library(dplyr)
library(agricolae)
library(car)
library(ggplot2)
```

Data:

```
data <- data.frame(truck = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 
                             2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1),
                   engine = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 4, 
                              1, 3, 4, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 4, 1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 2, 4),
                   performance = c(148.90352, 141.845295, 141.097055, 91.344735, 148.25445, 112.71164, 
                                   95.991155, 95.728895, 144.049595, 137.248695, 135.178345, 115.606135, 
                                   123.984355, 90.12156, 153.607515, 140.607315, 109.24445, 141.576455, 
                                   118.902715, 92.02365, 141.1034, 102.710275, 111.13949, 153.423275, 
                                   135.00421, 142.77284, 86.50397, 95.32399, 108.22126, 145.03589, 
                                   130.88701, 142.012145, 91.453305, 154.36915, 134.821145, 107.91435)
                   )
```

Code:

```
#Standard error of the mean function:
sem <- function(x) sd(x)/sqrt(length(x))

#ANOVA model and HSD code:
model1 <- lm(performance ~ truck + engine, data = data)
hsd=HSD.test(aov(model1), "truck", group=T)
hsd
```

The result of the HSD test that I need are here. Notice how the groups are re-arranged. This will be different than on the graph:

```
$groups
  performance groups
1    129.4063      a
3    128.4742      a
2    113.8464      b
```

Continuing on to graphing the data:

```
#Using dplyr to manipulate dataset:
truck <- select(data, truck, performance)
truck$truck <- as.factor(truck$truck)

#Aggregating mean and SEM:
truckMean <- aggregate.data.frame(truck, by=list(truck$truck), mean)
truckSem <- aggregate(performance ~ truck, truck, sem)

ggplot(truckMean, aes(x = Group.1, y = performance))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width = 0.4, position = "dodge", col = "black", fill = "maroon")+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = truckMean$performance, ymax = truckMean$performance + truckSem$performance), width = 0.2, position = position_dodge(0.6))+
  ggtitle("Truck Performance")+
  xlab("Truck type")+ylab("Performance")+
  theme(plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5, size = 15))+
  geom_text(label=hsd$groups$groups)
```

Graph results:

[image]

As you can see, the mean separation letters are in the wrong spot. **How can I change these letters so that they are above the right bar?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a `left_join` to join your `hsd` table and `truckMean` by the `performance` values and then plot that data.

```
truckMean<-left_join(truckMean,hsd$groups, by = "performance")
```

This is the only change you should made to your ggplot after doing the join (I added the value 20 to the y-coordinate values so the letters appear over the error bar):

```
geom_text(aes(y = performance+20, label = groups))
```